# How to get value from parent to child using SQL Procedures?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables 
1) parent
 
2) child

Now, I have a date field in parent table and i want to fetch the data from that date field of parent and copy that data in child table but only in date field using procedures. So, how can i write procedures to fetch the data from parent to child and display the date?

this is my parent form and date is already added

[image]

now this is my child and i want that date in my target date field by using procedures

[image]

Comment: Can you posts some example of both tables? And the result you are searching for.

Comment: Hi @Malay Dave, Could you please provide the snapshot of the objects and the expected result. so that it will help people to understand the question better.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Insert Into child (datefield)

Output inserted.datefield into #display

Select datefield from parent where ..

Select * from #display